# Пару десяток штук или пару десятков штук?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Ой, как резануло слух предложение: "Всего пару десяток штук и готово!!!" А ведь правильно будет сказать: "Всего пару десятков штук и готово!!!", не так ли? Мы же имеем в виду числительное, а не существительное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ой, да тут каждое слово надо обсуждать.

Начну от печки.
*«Пара»* здесь вообще не самое уместное числительное. *«Парой»* называется два предмета, дополняющие друг друга или составляющие единое целое. В отношении «десятков» такое употребление сомнительно.

Но если уж *«десятков штук»*, то именно *«десятков»* — от слова *«десяток»* выступающего в роли особой счетной единицы, а не *«десятка»* — нечто числом или номером десять.

При этом *«штук»* здесь совершенно лишнее. Десяток это и есть десять штук. (Я не беру вариант, что *«штука»* здесь в особом значении типа *«непочатый рулон сукна»* или «номер» см. здесь http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x.)

«Пару» или «пара» — это от падежа зависит. Если дать, взять или, там, сделать, то «пару», конечно. Если в именительном (пара десятков пройдёт), то «пара». Если без подразумеваемого глагола, то и так и этак можно.

Итак. Я бы сказал ***«Еще десятка два — и готово!»*** Всё остальное вызывает у меня разного рода претензии по грамматике или стилистике.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно, *десятков.* Только ещё правильнее будет, по-моему: "Ещё пар**а** десятков штук, и готово!"